# What are the bare minimum files that I should version in my Eclipse update-site?

Tags: git, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, update-site

I created an 'update-site' with Eclipse to distribute some plugins. Unfortunately, there's surprisingly little information online about how to track the development of the update-site (changes in plugin version, etc.) with git? Do I need to include everything or just the site.xml?